# Update Control.Tag property on TextChanged event - Performance concerns

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Am I going to take a big performance hit if I subscribe to the `TextBox.TextChanged` event and add text to its `Tag` property at every call?

```
private void textBox1.TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Note)listView.SelectedItems[0].Tag).Content = textBox1.Text;
}
```

I need to do this, but I am not sure how this will impact the performance (CPU-wise) of my app, and I am not sure how to measure the performance while these updates are taking place, either.

Comment: Why do you need this? If Note is your class I would suggest setting the textbox as a property of Note and have Note.content return the value of textbox.text.

Comment: @ZoharPeled It won't work that way unfortunately. And it's beside the point.

Comment: Where are you using `Tag`?

Comment: @DonBoitnott Sorry, I just realised I pasted the wrong code. I've updated it. I am using `Tag` in each ListViewItem.

Comment: As you are just assigning to a `Note` object's property, and assuming that the setter for `Content` isn't executing more code, the impact should be negligible.